# Attach Data to Pages $scope During AngularJS App Startup in .run

Tags: angularjs

I'm dynamically creating my routes in .run here:

```
.run(function($http, $rootScope) {
var mainInfo = null;
$http.get('thegoods.json').success(function(data) {
    $rootScope.HomeGateway = data.HomeGateway;
    var pages = $.merge($rootScope.HomeGateway.questions, $rootScope.HomeGateway.messages);
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        $routeProviderReference.when(pages[i].url, {
            templateUrl: pages[i].view,
            controller: pages[i].controller,
            data: pages[i].data
        })
    }
});
```

How can I access the data (defined as data: pages[i].data above). Note, I'm not sure if this is completely correct -- but it should serve as a demonstration of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically, I grab a JSON file and store it in $rootScope. I then use the $rootScope to dynamically create all the URLs. (Please see http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/how-to-defer-route-definition-in-an-angularjs-web-app/ if you are interested in doing this yourself) I want to be able to access data specific to certain pages without having to search through the JSON data again. I understand that it is an inexpensive operation but I'd like to do it the right way if possible.

Another way of phrasing my question would be.. how can I define each pages $scope at .run when the app first starts?

Comment: this is such an unusual way to do this, and what you are asking for doesn't really make sense.  `$scope` is created during the compile phase, why would you take all this trouble to try to avoid initializing pages early only to then ask how to initialize **every** page at `.run`?

Comment: I'm doing it this way because there's no way of using $http inside of .config and .run comes right after .config - do you know how I can access templateUrl from a given page?

Comment: I don't get what you gain by doing this;  Both `ngNewRouter` and `uiRouter` are VERY ROBUST packages that can handle multitudes of various configurations;  What is the benefit of defining client side routing in a `.json` file?

Comment: external application can define URL structure of website - I can't have my admins going into the javascript to change the URLs etc. - it's too confusing for them

Comment: to what end? is the external application writing the pages as well?  There isn't a way to do what you are asking because that's not how the framework was intended to be used, and why this would ever be something you would need to do is still not clear.

Comment: could create a resolve for your data

Comment: umm.. I think it's a pretty common feature to be able to define the site structure outside of the codebase

Comment: not for routes that are bound to the code that is responsible for the logic, it's not.... You can't just make a sitemap that magically resolves your application logic....  Keep in mind, as far as angular is concerned, routes are not just individual pages that aren't related; each route is a piece of the Single Page and it's functionality.

Comment: well I just did..

I just need to know how to get data from the $rootScope without having to search through the JSON to find which entry the URL is stored in. I'm doing this for code efficiency - I bet AngularJS 2 will support something like this

Comment: in my opinion, this is an anti-pattern, and using `$rootScope` is an anti-pattern as well.  However, there may be a reason to do this that I just don't understand, so I hope that someone else understands this better and is able to help you.  Good luck!

Comment: anyway... what is the preferred way of defining all the URLs of an AngularJS without touching the JavaScript? I know I could embed the json file using server-side scripting or grabbing the JSON in the header but I'd like to finish up using this method --- there's even a blogger that wrote a whole post about it :-)

Comment: why attach the json to `$rootscope`? the way you search for each property in the json file will be the same except you now need to put `$rootscope` in front of `HomeGateway`

Comment: i don't think there is anything wrong with dynamically defining routes for your application (maybe doing that off hardcoded json files is a maintenance overhead) but you should take a look at [ui-router's resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha) that @charlietfl recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all, written in [article, you share](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/how-to-defer-route-definition-in-an-angularjs-web-app/) is true, and I correctly understand all you want, then you should use `resolve` option of second parameter of `.when` function as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). And write smth like:

```
$routeProviderReference.when(pages[i].url, {
        templateUrl: pages[i].view,
        controller: pages[i].controller,
        resolve: {
            data: function(){
                return pages[i].data;
            }
        }
    });
```

And then in controllers:

```
function QuestionController($scope, data) {
    $scope.data = data.someProp;
}
```